# TimeZone Issue during DayLight Saving

Tags: unix, time-zone

I just been bugged by the Day light saving hours

I seem that `3rd November 2013 01:00:00` start EST time

Now ever Time I set my time to 3rd November 2013 00:58:xx(some seconds)

and run `date`

it give me valid Time zone i.e `EDT`

but

even after the time pass 01:00:00 and I still query the date library

I still see the Time zone as `EDT` and not `EST`

have a look at this screenshot [image]

You can clearly see the Time zone saying as EDT even when it is EST

any one has a clue for this

### Update

There is one other finding I found if I restart my machine I see this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is as expected.  [See this site for detailed confirmation](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=179&year=2013).  You may also want to review the description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info).

Since DST is ending in the fall, and the clocks move backwards, we call this the "fall back" transition.  As your clock is *approaching* 2:00 AM, it falls back to 1:00 AM instead.  The local time from 1:00:00 to 1:59:59.999 is repeated.  By the time 2:00 hits, it's already repeated the second instance of the 1:00 hour and DST is well over.

We use the label EDT for Eastern Daylight Time, when the offset is at UTC-04:00, and the label EST for Eastern Standard Time, when the offset is at UTC-05:00.  So no, EDT and EST are *not* the same.  It *does* matter which one you are in, especially during the 1:00 hour on the day of the transition.

The clock advances like this:

```
...
00:59:58 EDT (-0400)
00:59:59 EDT (-0400)
01:00:00 EDT (-0400)   --+
01:00:01 EDT (-0400)     |--- 1st instance of 1:00 hour
...                      |
01:59:59 EDT (-0400)   --+
01:00:00 EST (-0500)   --+  <----  transition
01:00:01 EST (-0500)     |
...                      |--- 2nd instance of 1:00 hour
01:59:59 EST (-0500)   --+
02:00:00 EST (-0500)
02:00:01 EST (-0500)
...
```

Also keep in mind that when you set the time to 1:00 local time, you aren't being specific enough.  Since there are two instances of 1:00, the OS will just pick one for you.  On Linux and Mac OSX the underlying system clock is kept in UTC.  1:00 EDT is at 5:00 UTC, while 1:00 EST is at 6:00 UTC.

Restarting your machine should have no effect.  My guess is that you didn't restart it right away, but allowed the time to elapse so it moved backward again.

**Additional Info**

Take a look at the [man page for the `date` command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html).  We can set the clock by the local time, using the somewhat strange format of `[[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]`  So this is 1:00 local time on the day of the transition:

```
date 110301002013
```

But that is not very specific, so the OS is probably picking EDT because it's the first instance.  It might as well pick EST though, since we didn't specify.

Instead, consider setting it by UTC:

```
date -u 110305002013       (1:00 EDT)

or

date -u 110306002013       (1:00 EST)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how `date` chooses its time-zone, but it can be over-ridden via the `TZ` environment variable.  The difference in your two screen shots (before/after re-booting) is because `date`'s default choice-of-time-zone got updated.  All times were always correct; it's only an issue of how the underlying time got printed as a string.

Don't know if this helps get at the root of your confusion, but I've found it helpful:

EDT and EST are *just* two different time-zones, and they both exist all year long. Usually one changes the default time-zone only when traveling, but in some regions, people also change their default time-zone at certain moments.  E.g. at 2013.Nov.03 05:59 GMT people on the east coast of U.S. tend to print times in EDT; at 2013.Nov.03 06:01 GMT they'll suddenly be printing all their dates in EST.

If somebody says "meet you at 14:30", you need to know what time-zone they're using to make it unambiguous.  @Matt's answer clarifies how people interpret time zone, when it's not explicitly stated.

Comment: I like to think of EST and EDT as two segments of the same ET zone (`America/New_York`).  And yes, some places do just stay on EST and never use EDT (ex: Cayman Islands).  Your description is mostly accurate.  The differences are just semantic.  Not sure how changing `TZ` variable would help though.

Answer (score 0):

edt and est are the same zone except edt is for summer (daylight time) and est is for winter (standard time). as long as your clock reads the correct time, it doesn't really matter. also est doesn't start til 2am not 1am.

Comment: See my update in the attach question

Comment: but the problem occur because of this every time I do Time.now(t1) is a ruby equivalent date unix library I give me EDT but the datetime  field store in mysql is converted into correct timezone by ruby i.e EST (t2) and as result when I try to find difference of t1-t2 it return me negative value

Comment: well if it is being corrected then what is the issue? how it got to be corrected doesn't matter if it is, right? I mean to say that if your clock is showing the correct time does it really matter if it says edt when you run Time.now. if mysql is correct then that is important because it is data. as long as it is either est or edt you are still in the et (eastern) time zone. Time.now may just not have updated itself to est yet because in screen shot you were at 1:13 am. est starts at 2 am.

Comment: Well the problem is like This I this piece of code Time.now - (Some time from database) Time.now which is equivalent to date of unix is giving me EDT time and Database is giving me EST time as result I getting a Negative value See attached screesnhot Technically you cannot have negative value if you only inspect the time on each case see [this](http://snag.gy/OZ6AZ.jpg) and [this](http://snag.gy/lf40O.jpg) to know what I meant

Comment: ok so it seems that mysql is jumping the gun so to speak. EST starts at 2AM and mysql is in EST an hour early. that means there is some kind of time zone mistake with mysql and Time.now is in a different time zone. Eastern time zone is UTC-5:00 This is what shows on your mysql screen shot. Atlantic Time Zone is UTC-4:00 and that is what your Time.now is showing according to your mysql screen shot. That means you need to change your Time.now to the Eastern Time Zone UTC-5:00.

Comment: mysql will most likely fix itself because we are in EST now. So I would check your unix time zone config. you might have it set to Atlantic -4:00

Comment: -1 because your description of DST is flat wrong.  Sorry.

Comment: @ Matt Johnson -10 to you. research before you speak. Read the following link about EST and EDT which is about DST. <http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/edt.html>

Comment: @jmc302005 - Please read my answer.  And believe me, I have plenty of research in this field.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/topusers) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/topusers) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datetime/topusers).  Your assumptions are simply incorrect.

Comment: Also, "Atlantic" time and "Eastern" time are two different zones.  An no, mysql will not "fix itself".

Comment: @user1328293 - You should be storing your times into the database in UTC, not in local time.  See [the "best practices" article here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/634824).

Comment: the fact of the matter is that we are both right. I even told the OP that one of her apps is wrong. and one is right. Maybe you missed that part. Being that it is so much later in the day and the OP is still saying the same thing I can only go by what is posted. Showing 2 different UTC will automatically make someone assume that the time zone is wrong on an app. I got no response as to weather or not the OP checked their location settings. So you assume your answer and I assume mine. Neither is wrong because we have no confirmation as to it being fixed.

Comment: Also The OP said they kept putting the clock back to 1:00 to see if it would fix itself. So no - anything. It is rude the way you commented. Mr. Ego Smartman.

Comment: By fix itself I meant it was already in EST time so when it past 2:00 it will be right. Esentially fixing itself. LMAO.

Comment: Your answer was technically inaccurate.  You said "est doesn't start until 2:00 AM", which is false.  It starts at 1:00 AM EST, which occurs as you are *approaching* 2:00 AM EDT.  You also said that EST and EDT the same thing and it doesn't matter - which is also false.  Resorting to [ad hominem attacks](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/ad-hominem) is a logical fallacy.  It is not ego if you are correct.

Comment: look up est time change. all over google it says 2:00am so i guess everyone is wrong. @not-just-yeti EST and EDT are not 2 different time zones they are both eastern one for summer (EDT) and one for winter(EST) for clarification read the link I posted. When I said EST and EDT are basically the same thing, that is correct in the sense that they are the same zone. so even if it stayed edt all winter you could just adjust the time and it will be correct time. As I said neither is wrong only not-just-yeti is completely wrong.

Comment: and the -4:00 in the op screen shot is what made me think it was maybe set to atlantic zone. I did forget it goes to -5:00 after EST starts.

Comment: You are correct in that the common knowledge is that the switch happens at 2:00, which is why Google reports it that way if you search.  But what is missing from the common knowledge is that the change happens precisely at *would become* 2:00.  So if your computer actually *reports* 2:00 to you, then a full hour has passed since the switch over and you are now seeing 2:00 EST.

Comment: @Matt Johnson You just proved me right. At 2am it goes back to 1am that is the start of EST. Thank you for proving it for me :)